# path is not ok on PHP project from other developer with different OS

Tags: php, windows

I have many errors, is there a way to force the `/` or `\` thing to use it on windows? cause it's a lot to change to work it again. 
for example like this, so many error because of this PHP file path...

this project came from Linux and I'm using windows.

[image]

and this is using Slim Framework + Twig
this is the code:

[image]

Comment: You should probably give some example of the code you're having trouble with. Windows should be perfectly happy using / for paths like this.

Comment: check update and added picture

Comment: I don't see a problem with that code. Again, Windows should be perfectly happy to use / here. Is there something else that is causing the problem?

Comment: Those are url not file paths anyway. The problem is probably to do with htaccess

Comment: ok i've fixed it already... the path is lack of name...